# Spring SimpleJdbcCall how to specify schema for an oracle STRUCT in a stored procedure call

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle

I am attempting to call a stored procedure that does not exist under my default schema. The procedure takes an oracle STRUCT as a parameter. Both the procedure and the oracle STRUCT live under the same schema: OTHERSCHEMA

Here is my code:

```
SimpleJdbcCall createMyCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
  .withSchemaName("OTHERSCHEMA")
  .withProcedureName("PROC_THEPROC")
  .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("Param_in", OracleTypes.STRUCT, "OTHERSCHEMA.MYTYPE"), 
    new SqlOutParameter(Param_out, OracleTypes.NUMBER),
    new SqlOutParameter(ErrorCode_out, OracleTypes.NUMBER));
Map in = Collections.singletonMap("Data_in", myData); 
createMyCall.execute(in);
```

When I execute this code, I am getting an error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; 
uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call OTHERSCHEMA.PROC_THEPROC(?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state 
[99999]; error code [17074]; invalid name pattern: MYSCHEMA.MYTYPE; nested exception is 
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: MYSCHEMA.MYTYPE
```

Why is OTHERSCHEMA.MYTYPE being replaced with my default schema MYSCHEMA? Some insight would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I resolved my problem. "myData" has a method getSQLTypeName() which was returning MYSCHEMA.MYTYPE. Apparently this will **ALWAYS**
override what I pass into SimpleJdbcCall.  Doh!!!

Comment: are you find a solution?